# Is there any site to ask about meaning of some words or phrases if I don't know whether they are Japanese or Chinese?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Japanese and Chinese words look similar. Is there any site where I can ask the meaning of words if I don't know whether they are Japanese or Chinese?

Comment: paste it into google translate and see what it says?

Comment: Look for [Hiragana & Katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system), it's only used in Japanese, then proceed to correct SE site. But if there's no hiragana/katakana (just a standalone Kanji), you need to provide more context (e.g. from where did you know the word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) would be the best option. It has a feature to auto-detect the language.

If you got the language, and you want to know more about the meaning (not the raw translation), you might want to check out the language-specific sites on the network, like [Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/) or [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/). Check out their help center to make sure your question is on-topic there.